# Angular JS http Bad Data Error

Tags: php, angularjs, json, httpserver

I am new to Angular. So I decided to make a sample login using Angular.
I send username and password to HTTP server. What I need is to get access into dashboard only if both username and password from the DB [php] should be same as user entered data.

I wrote the code and when tried to click on login button, I am getting the following error.

```
Error: [$http:baddata] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$http/baddata?p0=%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A%3Cb%3EFatal%20error%3C%2Fb%3E%3A%20%20Uncaught%20Error%3A%20Call%20to%20undefined%20function%20mysql_num_rows()%20in%20C%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cwebpage%5Cserver.php%3A20%0AStack%20trace%3A%0A%230%20%7Bmain%7D%0A%20%20thrown%20in%20%3Cb%3EC%3A%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cwebpage%5Cserver.php%3C%2Fb%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E20%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A&p1=%7B%7D Stack trace:
```

I am confused and don't know how to fix the issue. 
Please see the files attached and help me to solve this issue.

```
https://pastebin.com/MKsHVuFX - main.js
https://pastebin.com/JdSjf0Fe - dashboard.html
https://pastebin.com/hR6xwXde - server.php
https://pastebin.com/GGzetT3v - login.html
https://pastebin.com/YUiNw6z2 - index.html
```

Comment: You have `mysql_num_rows(result)`, but you saved your data in `$result`, so change it to `mysql_num_rows($result)`

Comment: Hello @AlekseySolovey I have changed, but still it's showing same error. Any Idea?

Comment: For PHP 5+ version I think you might need `mysqli_num_rows()` instead of `mysql_num_rows()`. (Also do something about your [**security**](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm))

Comment: Wow. Fixed the issue. Thanks for the info and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to visit the [url](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.9/docs/error/$http/baddata?p0=%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A%3Cb%3EFatal%20error%3C%2Fb%3E:%20%20Uncaught%20Error:%20Call%20to%20undefined%20function%20mysql_num_rows()%20in%20C:%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cwebpage%5Cserver.php:20%0AStack%20trace:%0A%230%20%7Bmain%7D%0A%20%20thrown%20in%20%3Cb%3EC:%5Cxampp%5Chtdocs%5Cwebpage%5Cserver.php%3C%2Fb%3E%20on%20line%20%3Cb%3E20%3C%2Fb%3E%3Cbr%20%2F%3E%0A&p1=%7B%7D) in the error message, because it's seems that your server side code is not retuning a valid json response that is mandatory for angularjs.

Check your server.php code, maybe is returning some warning/error.

Comment: Thanks. When I load the php file in URL, I am getting the following URL: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @DeepeshKumar that means you are trying to parse (maybe automatically) JSON data that is actually a PHP error

Comment: In your server.php you need to use mysqli functions, instead of mysql (is deprecated). Change it on line 20 in mysqli_num_rows and check for other errors.

Comment: Wow. Fixed the issue. Thanks for the info and solution.